# Unsupported codec error in heic to jpeg conversion using Imagick and php on EC2

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, imagick

I am trying to convert tiff and heic images to jpeg using Imagick, php(codeigniter3). Conversion is working fine in my local environment but throwing an error on ec2 instance.
tiff to jpeg conversion is working but heic to jpeg throwing an error.
Below is the error

> Error occured Unsupported feature: Unsupported codec (4.3000) `/tmp/magick--zIfCsRzhXQokvQJbnCeUjJkWJjb899g' @ error/heic.c/IsHEIFSuccess/135 in file /var/www/html/application/helpers/common_helper.php on 217

Below is the code I am using

```
try {
            
            $file_info['media_files']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['media_files']['tmp_name'];
            $file_info['media_files']['name'] = $_FILES['media_files']['name'];
            $url = realpath($file[$inputname]["tmp_name"]);
            $image_name = pathinfo($file[$inputname]['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $image = new Imagick($url);
            $image->setImageFormat('jpeg');
            return "data:image/jpeg;base64," . base64_encode($image);
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            echo '<pre>';print_r('error', 'Error occured ' . $ex->getMessage() . ' in file ' . $ex->getFile() . ' on ' . $ex->getLine());exit
        }
```

Imagick version is:

> convert -version
> Version: ImageMagick 7.1.0-40 beta Q16-HDRI x86_64 21a5642bc:20220620 https://imagemagick.org
> Copyright: (C) 1999 ImageMagick Studio LLC
> License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
> Features: Cipher DPC HDRI OpenMP(4.5)
> Delegates (built-in): bzlib fontconfig freetype heic jng jpeg lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff x xml zlib
> Compiler: gcc (7.3)

I tried checking libde265 and libheif as

```
ldconfig -p |grep libde265
ldconfig -p |grep libheif
```

not getting any output.

Any help would be appreciable. Thanks.